# Trying to set an item aside 70% of the time if 2 conditions are met in a SAS computer adaptive test simulation

Tags: sas, simulation

I am trying to adapt a computer adaptive test simulation to allow items to be set aside if the item difficulty is greater than .5 and the pocket that the item will go into for the time being is not full, but only 70% of the time.  If the item difficulty is less than .5 and the pocket is not full then the item will go into the pocket 50% of the time.  I am programming this in SAS and having a hard time finding how to do this only 70-50% of the time if the conditions are met.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Do you have access to SAS/OR?

Comment: I am using SAS Base for windows.  I have a couple if then statements (shown below) where I am taking the item that was selected and subtracting the examinee's ability.  If this difference is .5 higher than the ability then the item will be set aside in an array that I have set up, but only 70% of the time.  If the item is less than .49 higher than the ability it should go into the array, 50% of the time.  IF (SELINFO(W)-KTHETA GT .5) AND (POCKET<&IP) THEN SELINFO(W)=POCKET; /**NEED TO ADD ONLY 70% OF THE TIME**/
  IF (SELINFO(W)-KTHETA LT .49) AND (POCKET<&IP) THEN SELINFO(W)=POCKET;

  ELSE